# How to generate a thumb image?

Tags: image, resize, image-manipulation, imagemagick, image-resizing

I have a folder of about 20000 images, and I need to generate thumb images for them.

What's the fastest way to do this job?

I know I can do it using some image resizing libraries. But I am wondering maybe there's already a tool or code snippets that could do this job.

Comment: Interesting choice of tags...

Comment: retagged - The original question was about libraries.

Comment: If you're on Windows, http://imageresizing.net is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

imagemagick convert tool. It's a command line tool that works well both in Linux and Windows.

for converting a single image:

```
convert dragon.gif    -resize 50%  half_dragon.gif
```

Or, if you prefer thumbnails with a fixed size (here, 4096 pixels):

```
convert dragon.gif    -resize 4096@  pixel_dragon.gif
```

Or the most common use - resize into a given size:

```
convert dragon.gif    -resize 64x64  resize_dragon.gif
```

And for a large amount of image, quick-resize is available:

> The resize operator can also be
>   applied to images immediately after
>   being read, before it is added to the
>   current image sequence and the next
>   image is read.

So,

```
convert dragon.gif'[64x64]'    read_dragon.gif
```

Is probably the correct answer to your question.

These examples are taken from the [resize section](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/) of the imagemagick.org site; you can find numerous other examples there.

for converting a while library of images, you can write a small shell script, like:

```
for file in `ls`;
do
    convert $file  -resize 4096@ thumb_$file
done
```

For a very large amount of files, you might want to use Linux's `find -exec` to overcome the very long argument list which `ls` would yield.

Comment: why somebody downvotes this? at least i don't need to know any libraries. what i need is to generate a long .bat file:-|

but can 50% be changed to a absolute size?

Comment: Yes, use the '@' sign to determine the amount of pixels. I think you don't have to write a very long batch file - just a small loop which would iterate every file.

Comment: I'd like to write 8 .bat files and run them together to get some parallel. :)